# Can this pattern printing algorithm be written more efficiently?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, printf, time-complexity

This is my problem

```
//to print this diamond
     /*
        1
       121
      12321
     1234321
      12321
       121
        1 

       */
```

and this is the solution i tried , i visualized the problem as 6 right angled triangles and tried to solve as below

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

    //The number n is at the heart of the pattern ,4 in this case
    int i,j,k,l;
    int n=4;

    //do it in 2 steps top+bottom
    //consider we are in line 4 ie 1234321

        //top
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        //print spaces
            for(j=0;j<(n-i-1);j++)
            {
            printf(" ");
            }
        //print first half ie 1234
            for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
            {
            printf("%d",(k+1));
            }
        //print the second haf ie 321
            for(l=i;l>0;l--)
            {
            printf("%d",l);
            }
        //next line
        printf("\n");
        }

    //consider we are in line 5 ie 12321

        //bottom
        for(i=(n-2);i>=0;i--)
        {
        //print spaces
            for(j=(n-1);j>i;j--)
            {
            printf(" ");
            }
        //print left half ie 123
            for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
            {
            printf("%d",(k+1));
            }
        //print right half
            for(l=i;l>0;l--)
            {
            printf("%d",l);
            }
        //next line
        printf("\n");
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Now I need to reduce the number of loops used in this (not bothered about the actual time and space complexity much ) , my goal is to only reduce the number of loops , can anyone please suggest how to or try reducing the number of loops and answer

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of this, try to write the code in recursive manner, so that it can be used generally. It would really help you in reducing number of for loops

Comment: Yes but i would like any solution without recursion

Comment: What do you mean by `int n=9=4;`?

Comment: You could use `putchar()` instead of `printf()` to print single characters (`putchar(k + 1 + '0')` for the digits).  However, that doesn't alter the number of loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`abs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/) function to get the increasing/decreasing sequences:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const int N = 5; /* center value = length of edge of diamond */
  int i, j, k;
  for( i=1 ; i<2*N ; ++i ) {
    j = N-abs(N-i); /* center value of row */
    printf( "% *d", N-j+2, 1 );
    for( k=2 ; k<2*j ; ++k ) putchar( j-abs(j-k)+'0' );
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
     1
    121
   12321
  1234321
 123454321
  1234321
   12321
    121
     1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `min` function to replace the two 'digit' loops with one:

```
static inline int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }

int N = 2 * (n - 1);
for (int k = 0; k <= N; k++)
    putchar(min(k, N-k) + '0' + 1);
```

For `n == 4`, `N == 6`, and you get:

```
k    0   1   2   3   4   5   6
N-k  6   5   4   3   2   1   0
min  0   1   2   3   2   1   0
```

and you then print the digit corresponding to 'min + 1'.  The cost of doing this is the conditional in the `min` function on each iteration.

If you really insist, you can do more conditional computation inside a loop over a larger range, printing spaces when the index is below one threshold and printing digits using a formula based on the `min` function after the threshold.

Answer (score 3):

You can offload the image generation into a function to reduce the loop count to two:

```
char diamondChar(int x, int y) {
    if(x < 0) x = -x;
    if(y < 0) y = -y;
    int value = 4 - x - y;
    return (value <= 0) ? ' ' : '0' + (char)value;
}

int main() {
    for(int y = -3; y <= 3; y++) {
        for(int x = -3; x <= 3; x++) {
            putchar(diamondChar(x, y));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```